# Processing log files: Apache Storm or Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-storm, logfiles

I have a requirement to process log file data. It is relatively trivial. I have 4 servers with 2 web applications running on each for a total of 8 log files. These get rotated on a regular basis. I'm writing data in the following format into these log files

Source Timestamp :9340398;39048039;930483;3940830

Where the numbers are identifiers in a data store. I want to set up a process to read these logs and for each id it will update a count depending on the number of times its id has been logged. It can either be real time or batch. My interface language to the datastore is Java. The process runs in production so needs to be robust but also needs to have a relatively simple architecture so it is maintainable. We also run zookeeper.

My initial thought was to do this in a batch whenever the log file is rotated running an Apache spark on each server. However I then got to looking at log agregators such as Apache Flume, Kafka and Storm, but this seems like overkill.

Given the multitude of choices has anyone got any good suggestions as to which tools to use to handle this problem based on experience?

Comment: Perhaps solutions like [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) can be of use? Generally, these sorts of questions are off-topic on SO.

Comment: Hi, I looked at Logstash, it seemed more oriented towards filtering type operations. I agree this question isn't a good fit for the SO charter.

Answer (score 1):

8 log files don't seem to warrant any "big data" technology. If you do want a play/get started with these type of technology I'd recommend you'd start with Spark and/or Flink - both have relatively similar programming model both both can handle "business real-time" (Flink is better at streaming but both would seem to work in your case). Storm is relatively rigid (hard to change topologies) and has a more complex programming model

Comment: I tend to agree that it is not  a "big data" problem. It just occurred to me that there should be some reasonably simple tools to deal with the problem of log aggregation and processing in a robust way even for small data problems. I may not even need log aggregation as the data source can handle updates from divers applications. So something to either tail the log file or do period batch processing might be the solution.

Comment: Have you considered ELK or Fluentd?  If you want pure JAVA, Flume may be another one but it does not have reliable tail. The native tail may be available in 1.7 release but not sure when. I would suggest very simple logstash or filebeats config and forward to Elastic where you can do simple aggregation on term.

Comment: I looked at ELK but may take a second look given what you said.